# How to completely disable laptop sound?

Tags: audio, windows-8

I have a HP Pavillion DV7 laptop with win 8 pro.
The laptop has an unidentified problem with sound drivers or hardware that sometimes causes volume to constantly jiggle up and down. This is very annoying because of these consequences:

- Renders mute unusable - as the volume changes the sound unmutes automatically
- Causes an annoying win 8 "surface UI" notification to appear constantly in the upper left corner, which is distracting enough by itself, but more importantly
- Renders the whole "surface UI" unusable, because it loses focus whenever the sound changing notification appears
- When the jiggling happens, the laptop also loses the ability to redirect sound to earphones - sound comes out of the speakers even if earphones are connected.

To solve these issues I want to completely disable sound in the laptop (I've tried reinstalling drivers several times to no end).
I have tried disabling all sound related drivers and devices in the Device Manager but Windows re-enables those automatically whenever I restart the laptop. The BIOS doesn't have any settings to disable sound hardware either.

Please don't suggest having the laptop sound serviced or fixed. It's not worth the expense. I just want to remove sound support so I can use it normally. It is very unusable as it is now.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer because it doesn't really answer your question. But the best solution is to either get the laptop repaired or ditch Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather not play with the hardware directly, you can always disable the sound driver via Control Panel > Device Manager > Devices > Sound (right click, Disable)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I did that but Windows re-enables it on startup, on its own

Comment: Try disabling the Windows Audio service.  Also, are you sure it's the sound hardware and not bad volume keys?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is disable the audio device in BIOS.  That way Windows (or any OS) will not even detect that there is a sound device.  I can not speak for your model of laptop & BIOS, but for the HP I have, I would boot into BIOS, go to System Configuration, then Built-In Device Options then disable onboard audio.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disconnect the speaker completely. [This link](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/disassemble-hp-pavilion-dv7-notebook/) shows how to get to it, and Step 12 explains how to disconnect the speaker cable. You can even remove the entire speaker assembly.

Comment: Incidentally, how possible do you think it'd be to wire the wifi cable to a manual switch instead of the touch button in the media strip? That strip is the worst hardware design idea and implementation ever...

Comment: I'd rather not mess with the hardware though, as previous attempts have left the screws wasted so it'd be quite difficult

Comment: The wifi button is a soft-switch, which sends a command, presumably to a wifi chip. I don't know where the actual switching is done, but it's not at that button.

Comment: But I suppose you could rewire it to another pushbutton, if you can find a suitable one - and a place to install it...

Answer (score 0):

Device manager lets you disable sound devices, but you need to disable the sound **controllers** , not just the speakers, since these do in my experience continue to work after a reboot. Got frustrated by that, but disabling the controllers did it for me, but I had to reboot (not an issue after this much fighting) to disable all of the controller drivers (Windows 10 Thinkpad/Lenovo in my case) and 7 years too late to be any help.

Comment: The question says “I have tried disabling all sound related drivers and devices in the Device Manager …”  What, *exactly,* should the user do that they are not already doing?

Comment: quite often using a hammer when you don't need to is going to leave dents, just the controllers https://imageshack.com/i/pmCLrBg8p